# How to fix/disable seemingly erroneous "No named exports found in module" error?

Tags: eslint, es6-modules

I'm linting my code and I'm getting this in a couple places:

```sh
/Users/zane/playground/react-waiter/js/components/index.js
  1:15  error  No named exports found in module './utils'    import/export
  2:15  error  No named exports found in module './widgets'  import/export

/Users/zane/playground/react-waiter/js/index.js
  1:15  error  No named exports found in module './components'  import/export
```

I believe the report is a false positive because when I run the code, everything works fine and I can indeed import the exported items.

The code:

```
// js/index.js
export * from './components'
export * from './settings'
export * from './utils'
```

```
// js/components/index.js
export * from './utils'
export * from './widgets'
```

```
// js/components/utils/index.js
export * from './Waiter'
```

```
// js/components/utils/Waiter.jsx
...
const Waiter = (props) => { ... }

export { Waiter }
```

Then the same pattern for the `widgets` module, a single constant exported from the file and re-exported from the index. I did 
try `export const Waiter = ...`, and `export * from './utils/index'` with the same result.

I use this pattern a lot, and the problem occurs when re-exporting an index file and nothing else.

As a workaround, I set the eslint config to change these to warnings so they don't stop the CI process, but true problems still get reported.

I assume at some point the (apparent) bug will be fixed. This would be a minor issue, but  `/* eslint-disable import/export */` seems to have no effect.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Is there a way to disable the rule on a per-line basis and/or "jiggle" things so eslint properly reports things?

Comment: can you post your package.json? i started a new create-react-app and reproduced your situation without error

Comment: It's rather large, but it's on github. The linting is done from [catalyst-scripts](https://github.com/Liquid-Labs/catalyst-scripts/blob/master/package.json) and the project with the lint errors is [react-waiter](https://github.com/Liquid-Labs/react-waiter).

Answer (score 3):

To disable this rule your `.eslintrc.js` should have:

```
module.exports = {
    'rules': {
        'import/export': 0
    }
}
```

Comment: I currently have it set to 'warning' so that correct lints still get seen but auto-checking doesn't stop progress in the CI pipeline.